# How to add Google recaptcha to a custom form?

Tags: 7, forms, captcha

I have a form I'm creating programmatically with a custom module, and I need to add the Google recaptcha to it. In the [Google reCaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_recaptcha) module's settings page (/admin/config/spam_protection/google_recaptcha/forms) I only see the login, register and comments forms and no way to add a custom form (like in the captcha module).

I googled as well as looked in the Google Captcha module's files and API file and can't find any hooks or info on how I can add the captcha element to a custom form. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **recaptcha** module (https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha)
and in captcha settings(admin/config/people/captcha) you can add your custom form's form_id and select the challenge type reCAPTCHA(from module recaptcha). This should work.

Comment: Interestingly, the captcha module doesn't work with the form_id if the custom form's function name is different. So if the custom function that creates the form is `function foo_form()` and the form id is set to `bar_form` inside the form function, I had to put `foo_form` in the captcha's settings.

Comment: For those coming here for Drupal 8, I've written a guide here to setting up Captcha for a form (specific focus in the instructions is for making use of the form id, which might not be obvious enough for some): https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha/issues/2736881#comment-13594561